# Import Excel dates to Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, date

I have a number of dates in an Excel file associated with some other numbers, then I want to import this data in Matlab.

E.g. I have 5/17/06 on Excel and in Matlab it appears as 0.0490196078431373
when I try to import it..

How can I import the dates correctly into matlab??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how are you importing the dates currently? Have you tried using xlsread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea of what you need to do.

```
[A B C] = xlsread('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.xlsx') %This is just a dummy file I made to test with.
```

B will contain the data from the excel file.  It is VERY important to note that it will be the exact same as the layout from excel.  This is what I have in the dummy file:

```
5/17/06     asd     12
5/18/06     s       sd
5/19/06     asd     asd
5/20/06     dsd     sd
5/21/06     e2      asd
```

So the resulting matrix `B` will be a cell array with 3 columns and 5 rows.  You can then pull the date out into a separate matrix like so:

```
date = B(:,1)
```

Now `date` is a vector of cells that contain the dates you had before.  You can then apply other functions to convert to a char array (string) if you want to, etc.